why z index not working on :after position absolute and parent position relative
I want to create background using pseudo element :after, and I use z index to set the order so that it is below the other elements, but not working.
Thanks in advance.


body {
    background: #000;
}
.container {
    width: 375px;
    height: 700px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.container::after {
    content: "";
    width: 375px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: pink;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    opacity: .75;
    z-index: 1;
}
.nav {
    background-color: green;
    z-index: 9;
}
.header {
    z-index: 8;
}
<div class="container">
      <div class="nav">
        <h1>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing.</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="header">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</h2>
      </div>
    </div>



